# Проблема передачи ассоциативного массива из php в js

Tags: php, javascript, json, файлы

Имеется файл с расширением php, в нем реализован сбор информации из БД. Необходимо эти данные(ассоциативный массив) передать в js, который так, же подключен к данному файлу.

```
<?php
    require('../db.php');

    function var_dump1($arr) {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($arr);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    // load data from Database
    $query = R::getAll('SELECT * from questions');
    var_dump1($query);

    $query = json_encode($query);
    var_dump1($query);
?>

<script>
const arr = '<?=$query; ?>';
console.log(arr);

</script>
```

Outputs:

> var_dump1($query);

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["question"]=>
    string(143) "The ______________ of a table is used to modify the design of a table, like modifying the name of a field or changing the data type of a field."
    ["answer1"]=>
    string(14) "Datasheet View"
    ["answer2"]=>
    string(11) "Desisn View"
    ["answer3"]=>
    string(10) "Table View"
    ["answer4"]=>
    string(11) "Wizard View"
    ["true_answer"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["question"]=>
    string(83) "You can select multiple fields of a table in design view by using the ________ key."
    ["answer1"]=>
    string(3) "Alt"
    ["answer2"]=>
    string(8) "Spacebar"
    ["answer3"]=>
    string(5) "Shift"
    ["answer4"]=>
    string(4) "Ctrl"
    ["true_answer"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
...
```

> var_dump1($query);

```
string(1302) "[{"id":"1","question":"The ______________ of a table is used to modify the design of a table, like modifying the name of a field or changing the data type of a field.","answer1":"Datasheet View","answer2":"Desisn View","answer3":"Table View","answer4":"Wizard View","true_answer":"...
```

> console.log(arr);

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Вывод:

Из выше перечисленного видно, что на стороне php данные нормально подгружаются из БД, потом так же корректно преобразуются в JSON, но при попытке принять данный JSON и преобразовать в js объект выбивает ошибку.

Вопросы:

1. Как подгрузить данные(например, ассоциативный массив, как в моем случае) из php в js, когда php и js находится в одном файле, с расширением php
2. Как подгрузить данные(например, ассоциативный массив, как в моем случае) из php в js, если php и js находятся в разных файлах. Например, есть файл с расширением php, где только логика, и оттуда нужно переместить данные в другой файл, с расширением js.

Comment: @And, так я его же завернул в json `$query = json_encode($query);` а в js, пробывал как вы говорите делать `const arr = '<?=$query; ?>';
const arr_obj = JSON.parse(arr);` но ничего не работает, так же ошибку выдает

Comment: Я проверил, пример рабочий! Возможно вы не верно оформили вопрос и проблему не видно, возможно проблема в кавычках, так-как, нужно экранировать их.

Answer (score 0):

Передайте json из php в js:

php

```
$json = json_encode($query);
echo "<script>var arr ='$json';</script>";
```

js

```
var parseArr = JSON.parse(arr);
```

Comment: не получается, только + 1 ошибка добавилась: _Uncaught ReferenceError: arr is not defined_

Comment: _arr is not defined_ видимо потому, что у вас js выполняется до построения DOM, т.е. обращение к arr происходит когда ее еще не существует.